# How to deploy on online and offline targets with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I have an Azure DevOps Continuous Deployment definition with 2 stages and multiple targets. The 2 stages are "staging" and "production". I have 4 targets, 4 agents (same agent) installed on 4 PC. One is tagged as staging and the 3 others are tagged as production.

My staging PC/agent is always ON... always online.
My 3 other targets I don't have the control. I rarely have the 3 production PC/agent online at the same time. Each PC can be offline and it is not an error.

How can I create a correct Continuous Deployment definition that try to deploy when an agent is online?

On next screen you can see the fail on production stage

[image]

And the details:

[image]

Because one of my targets is not online, I get a failure. How can I ask the system to retry? Let's say during 24h before returning a failure? Is it possible? Is it possible to trigger the deployment based on the status "online" of the agent?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a polling pipeline - scheduled per hour or 30 mins or some different polling mechanism (eg. time triggered azure function) to check if the targeted agent(s) are online.

That pipeline/mechanism should consist of the API calls to [Azure DevOps agent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents?api-version=7.0
```

From the above, you will get the [task agent status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#taskagentstatus) information.

Using that info, based on the online availability of the agents, you can trigger the required pipeline.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a gate on the **Pre-deployment conditions** of production stages following below steps:

1. Go to **Project Settings** > **Service connections**, create a [**Generic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#generic-service-connection) type service connection.

   - **Server URL:** **`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis`**
   - **Password/Token Key:** Your PAT which should have the "**`Deployment Groups (Read & manage)`**" scope at least.

     [image]
   - Give a name to this service connection.

   [image]
2. Open the release pipeline definition, and open the **Pre-deployment conditions** of production stages to set the gate.
3. Enable the **Gates** option and add a **Invoke REST API** task to the gate.

   [image]
4. On the **Invoke REST API** task, set below options.

   - **The delay before evaluation:** **`0 Minutes`**
   - Give a customized **Display name** to the task, if you like.
   - **Connection type:** **`Generic`**
   - **Generic service connection:** The name of Generic service connection created above.
   - **Method:** **`GET`**
   - **Headers:** Can keep the default value.
   - **URL suffix and parameters:** **`/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/{deploymentGroupId}/targets?tags=production&agentStatus=online&enabled=true&api-version=7.0`**

   [image]

   - **Completion event:** **`ApiResponse`**
   - **Success criteria:** **`ge(root['count'], 1)`**

   [image]

   - **The time between re-evaluation of gates:** Can be 5 to 1440 in minutes, or 1 to 24 in hours.
   - **Minimum duration for steady results after a successful gates evaluation:** **`0 Minutes`**
   - **The timeout after which gates fail:** **`1 Days`** or more
   - Other options can keep the default values, or you can change them based on your actual needs.

   [image]
5. Save above changes on the release pipeline definition.

This gate is using the Invoke REST API task to call the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Targets - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" to list all the deploy agents which have the '**`production`**' tag and are **`enabled`** and **`online`**.

- If the returned count is less than 1, the gate evaluation failed and wait for the next evaluation until the evaluation successful or reach the specified timeout (**1 Day**).

[image]

- If the returned count is greater than or equal to 1, evaluation successful, then start the deployment on one of the **`online`** status deploy agents.

[image]

For more information, you can reference the following documents:

- [**Targets - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)
- [**Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#ge)
- [**Deployment gates**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops)
- [**Invoke REST API task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/invoke-rest-api-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)